# Reverse proxy deployment of React apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, docker, express

I'm trying to deploy multiple containerised SPAs using a reverse proxy to handle routing to each. In the current setup, each container has a production build create-react-app served by an express app which essentially just consists of:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build')));

app.use('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
});)
```

I've configured an nginx server with the following:

```
server {
    listen 8081;
    server_name example.domain.com;
    location /app1 {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3100;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:3100 https://example.domain.com/app1;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

The proxying appears to work as when I navigate to `http://localhost:8081/app1` the `index.html` of the built React app loads but all of the bundled js files are 404. I have tried setting `"homepage": "/app1"` in the React app's `package.json` but this hasn't appeared to make any difference. It is still looking for the bundled js files at the server's root: `Request URL: http://localhost:8081/static/js/bundle.js`

I'm at a loose end as to what to try next, any help would be much appreciated.

Best,

P

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a static middleware, i.e.

```html
app.use(express.static('static'))
```

Or

```
app.use('static', express.static('static'))
```

*static* is the folder name of all your static asset.
See: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

**Updated:**

If you have a folder "static" under "build", please use :

app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'static')));

Comment: I'll edit the question to show that line, I already have `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build')));` in the express app that lives with the React app in the container

Comment: I assume you have a static folder under build folder, 
In this case, you please try:
`app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'static')));`

Comment: modified multiple times, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That hasn't seemed to change anything. I've think I've discovered though that for whatever reason the "homepage" directive somehow isn't propagating when I deploy the app in docker. If I build and run locally with homepage set to "app1" then it attempts to load static files from `http://localhost:3100/app1/static/js/1.13eeb203.chunk.js` but when I run the build in a container it's looking at `http://localhost:8081/static/js/bundle.js` (which will be proxied to `http://localhost:3100/static/js/bundle.js` whereas the files exist at `http://localhost:3100/app1/static/js/bundle.js`)

Comment: If I set the following: `app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'static')));
app.use('/test', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build')));` and run the app locally then `localhost:3100/test` loads correctly, and `localhost:3100/static` gives a 404

Comment: I got there in the end, turns out a few things were required: modifying the Dockerfile to behave as I was expecting, and modifying the nginx proxy_pass directive to appropriately alter the url hitting the express app. Thanks for your help!